# Ajax call in .Net and Azure

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, azure

I have an Ajax function that works fine on my local machine, when running my site locally.  But, when on Azure, if one of the parameters has a line break, an error occurs:  "The specified URL cannot be found ", which is a 404 error for the asmx file/function.  Having line breaks does not cause issues on my local machine, when running locally.  On Azure, if there are no line breaks, the code runs fine.  Any suggestions on why this could occur and how to address it?  Here is my code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'GeneralWebServices.asmx/CreateNewContent',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: '{"org_name": "' + orgName + '", "org_description": "' + orgDescription + '", "org_id": ' + orgId + ', "org_acronym": "' + orgAcronym + '", "parent_id": "' + parent_id + '", "org_level": "' + orgLevel + '", "org_orderBy": '+ org_orderBy +' }',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (response) {
            var resp = $.parseJSON(response);
            resp = $.parseJSON(resp.d).Success;
            //do stuff
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            ShowMessage("error", "Error Saving Details");
        }
    });
```

An example payload would be:

> "{"org_name": "Some Text",
>   "org_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit, sed
>
> do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
>   "org_id": 11734, "org_acronym": "ABC", "parent_id": "0", "org_level":
>   "SomeVal", "org_orderBy": 0 }"

Removing the line break, like this:

> "{"org_name": "Some Text",
>   "org_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
>   elit, seddo eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua",
>   "org_id": 11734, "org_acronym": "ABC", "parent_id": "0", "org_level":
>   "SomeVal", "org_orderBy": 0 }"

Would not cause an issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try stringify instead of building the json by hand.

```
const data = {
  org_name: orgName,
  org_description: orgDescription, // ...and so on
};

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'GeneralWebServices.asmx/CreateNewContent',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (response) {
            var resp = $.parseJSON(response);
            resp = $.parseJSON(resp.d).Success;
            //do stuff
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            ShowMessage("error", "Error Saving Details");
        }
    });
```